# How to call non static method from AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json

Here is my code behind I am calling from AJAX...

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static string save(string parameter)
    {
        country_master obj_country = new country_master();
        obj_country.Country_Name = Page.Request.Params["name"].ToString().Trim();
        obj_country.saved();
        return "";
    }
```

Here I am not able to access parameters passed from the page via Page.Request.

```
string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].Trim();
return "error";
```

after writing the first line, return statement does not return anything to the AJAX.
Please Help me how to do that.
Thanks...

Comment: No, you cannot call a non static method from ajax, in asp.net webforms and to access Context properties, you can use `HttpContext` static class.

Comment: `obj_country.Country_Name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString['name'].Trim()`

Comment: Thanks for the help
country_master obj_country = new country_master();
        obj_country.Country_Name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].Trim();
return "error";
after writing these code return statement does not return anything to the AJAX. Please Help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current context you can use `HttpContext.Current`, which is a static property.

Once you have that you can access things like session or profile and get information about the state of the site

`HttpContext.Current.Session` etc..

This link may help you : [Call Server Side via AJAX without a Static Method](http://www.jbcdigital.com/call-non-static-server-side-methods-via-microsofts-ajax.aspx)

**The reason behind restricting the web method to be static is to avoid it access the controls of the  instance page.**

Comment: Thanks for the help 

country_master obj_country = new country_master(); obj_country.Country_Name = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].Trim(); 
return "error"; 

after writing these code return statement does not return anything to the AJAX. Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

Yo could use the `HttpContext.Current` static class, however you can skip that if you declare on your method the parameters you want to use and just pass the parameters with your AJAX call

You should pass parameters directly to the method.

I have several working examples [on my Github repository](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/JQuery/Ajax/PageMethods_JQueryAJAX.aspx), feel free to browse the code.

As a summary, to call a PageMethod:

Note: how using AJAX the `jobID` PageMethod parameter is being passed along with the request and how is used inside the PageMethod transparently

#### AJAX call

```
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%: this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Topics/JQuery/Ajax/PageMethods_JQueryAJAX.aspx/GetEmployees") %>',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{"jobID" : ' + jobID +'}',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#employees').find('option').remove();
                    $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
                        $('<option />').val(item.EmployeeID).text(item.FirstName).appendTo('#employees');
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

#### Page Method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees(int jobID)
    {
        var ctx = new PubsDataContext();

        return (from e in ctx.employee
                where e.job_id == jobID
                orderby e.fname
                select new EmployeeModel
                {
                    EmployeeID = e.emp_id,
                    FirstName = e.fname
                }).ToList();
    }
```